# pipes for each evaluates before sending downstream?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

going through the [pipes tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.2/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html) led to toying with some examples:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

f1 :: Show a => Int -> [a] -> IO ()
f1 n xs = runEffect $ (for (each xs) (lift . putStrLn . show))
            >-> P.take n
            >-> P.stdoutLn

f2 :: Show a => Int -> [a] -> IO ()
f2 n xs = runEffect $ each xs
            >-> P.map show
            >-> P.take n
            >-> P.stdoutLn
```

but the above produces:

```
>>> f1 3 [1..10]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
>>> f2 3 [1..10]
1
2
3
>>>
```

contrary to my expectation that f1 and f2 would produce the same result (namely the result of f2). the question is: why don't they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For has the type signature of:

```
for
  :: Monad m =>
     Proxy x' x b' b m a'
     -> (b -> Proxy x' x c' c m b') -> Proxy x' x c' c m a'
```

You second parameter for your `for` is:

```
(lift . putStrLn . show)
```

Which is has a type of `b -> Proxy ...`, but does not yield anything downstream since `yield` is absent.  This means that `P.take` and `P.stdoutLn` never run. Since `P.take` does not receive any values it does not ever shutdown the pipeline.

If you wanted to print the value with `for` and yield downstream you could:

```
f1 :: Show a => Int -> [a] -> IO ()
f1 n xs = runEffect $ (for (each xs) 
                           (\x -> (lift . putStrLn . show) x >> yield x))
            >-> P.show
            >-> P.take n
            >-> P.stdoutLn


> f1 3 [1..10]
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

edit:

Here are some additional code samples based on `f1` using `for`:

```
f3 :: Show a => Int -> [a] -> IO ()
f3 n xs = runEffect $ for (each xs >-> P.take n) (lift . putStrLn . show)  

f4 :: Show a => Int -> [a] -> IO ()
f4 n xs = runEffect $ each [1..10] >-> for (P.take n) (lift . putStrLn . show)

> f3 3 [1..10]
1
2
3
> f4 3 [1..10]
1
2
3
```

Comment: To be slightly more precise, both `take` and `stdoutLn` in the original example do briefly run up until they reach their first `await` statement and then they never regain control.

Comment: Also, you can use `Pipes.Prelude.chain` to easily run an action and reforward the original input further downstream.